# stop watcher service on application quit

Tags: java, watchservice

I use `gradle` and `application` plugin to run the application that watches the changes in the directory.

My main class looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    WatcherThread thread = new WatcherThread(EXTENSION_FOLDER);
    thread.start();

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        String input = null;
        ConsoleInputController controller = new ConsoleInputController(br);
        while (!QUIT_COMMAND.equals(StringUtils.trim(input))) {
            System.out.println(CONSOLE_TEMPLATE);
            System.out.println("input (to exit write [quit]):> ");

            input = br.readLine();
            controller.handleInput(input);
        }
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to process input.", exc);
    }

    thread.stopThread();
}
```

`WatcherThread` is a thread class that uses `WatcherService` (some wrapper over `WatchService` of java)

```
public class WatcherThread extends Thread {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WatcherThread.class);

    private boolean watch = true;
    private WatcherService watcherService;

    public WatcherThread(String searchingPath) throws IOException {
        watcherService = new WatcherService(Paths.get(searchingPath));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LOGGER.info("Artifact watching thread started.");
        while(watch) {
            if (!watcherService.watch()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        LOGGER.info("Artifact watching thread stopped.");
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        watch = false;
    }
}
```

`WatcherService` looks like this

```
public class WatcherService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WatcherThread.class);

    private final WatchService watcher;
    private final Map<WatchKey, Path> keys;
    private boolean trace;

    WatcherService(Path dir) throws IOException {
        watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        keys = new HashMap<>();

        register(dir);

        trace = true;
    }

    private void register(Path dir) throws IOException {
        WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
        if (trace) {
            Path prev = keys.get(key);
            if (null == prev) {
                LOGGER.info("Register path: [{}].", dir);
            } else {
                if (!dir.equals(prev)) {
                    LOGGER.info("Updated path: [{}] -> [{}].", prev, dir);
                }
            }
        }
        keys.put(key, dir);
    }

    boolean watch() {
        WatchKey key;
        try {
            key = watcher.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            return false;
        }

        Path dir = keys.get(key);
        if (null == dir) {
            LOGGER.warn("WatchKey is not recognized!");
            return false;
        }

        // forEach?
        for (WatchEvent event: key.pollEvents()) {
            LOGGER.info("Polling events");
            WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
            if (OVERFLOW == kind) {
                continue;
            }

            WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
            Path name = ev.context();
            Path child = dir.resolve(name);

            LOGGER.info("Event occurred [{}] in [{}].", event.kind().name(), child);
            WatchEventResolver.resolveEvent(ev, child);
        }

        boolean valid = key.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            keys.remove(key);

            if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

When I do not `start` my `WatcherThread` - console input works fine. I can `quit` for example without problems. But when I run thread and want to quit, it is waiting for couple of seconds and then only ends.

As far as I understand it is something with `WatchService` that cannot stop watching the directory.

How to stop it on `quit` application immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need an extra method in your `WatcherService` class, that calls to `watcher.close()`. Then, in your `WatcherThread` class you can call to that method inside `stopThread()`.

In the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#take()) for `WatchService` you can see that `take()` keeps waiting. You can force it to finish by closing it.

Comment: well it throws `ClosedWatchServiceException` if I call `close` in `stopThread`.

Comment: Exactly, then you can handle it same as `InterruptedException` in your code.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks!